# django makemessage DjangoUnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, translation

I'm using django translation, and I have an error when i try to make `./manage.py makemessages --locale es`

This is the error:

`DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 32: invalid start byte. You passed in '<HTML>\n<HEAD>    \n\t<TITLE> meta \xbc\xd0\xc5\xd2\xaa\xba\xa8\xcf\xa5\xce\xa1G\xa4\xa4\xa4\xe5\xba\xf4\xad\xb6 </TITLE>\n\t<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=big5">\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n\n\xb3o\xacO\xa4@\xad\xd3\xc1c\xc5\xe9\xa4\xa4\xa4\xe5\xba\xf4\xad\xb6\xa1I<br>\n(This page uses big5 character set.)<br>\ncharset=big5\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>' (<type 'str'>)`

someones have a idea?

Comment: please give us your full traceback and your files project...

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem with this line `./manage.py makemessages --locale es --ignore folder_name`. Was needed to ignore the angular modules.